# Simplecv and openkinect blob detection issues

Tags: python, robotics, simplecv, openkinect

I am currently on a robotics team for my high school and my objective is to use our kinect to detect the balls in this year's game by using simplecv and openkinect. I am currently stuck on an issue that my mentors and I cannot seem to resolve. What the code does is it takes a live-depth map feed from the kinect and binarizes it, once it has done that it looks for blobs and tries to find the circular blobs. Finally it draws a circle over the circular blob. The issue is the code is able to find blobs no problem, but it's not able to find the circular ones. I am at a dead end and am hoping someone in the community will be able to please help me. Thank you, here's the code and an image of what is seen

```
from SimpleCV import *
cam = Kinect()
display = SimpleCV.Display()
while display.isNotDone():
    depth = cam.getDepth().flipHorizontal()
    img2 = cam.getImage().flipHorizontal()

    filtered = depth.stretch(200,255)
    segmented = filtered.binarize(200)
    blobs = segmented.findBlobs()
    if blobs:
        circles = blobs.filter([b.isCircle() for b in blobs])
        if circles:
            img2.drawCircle((circles[-1].x, circles[-1].y), circles[-1].radius(),SimpleCV.Color.RED,3)
            img2.drawText("FOUND A BALL", 50,50,color=Color.RED,fontsize=48)

    img2.sideBySide(segmented).show()
```

[image]

Comment: Provide a link to your image, someone with more rep will post it inline for you.

Comment: Ok, thank you for letting me know. http://imgur.com/btMmvGa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem, here is the new version of the code that works. Sorry, no screen cap this time.

```
import SimpleCV
from SimpleCV import *
display = SimpleCV.Display()
cam = Kinect()
normaldisplay = True

while display.isNotDone():

    if display.mouseRight:
        normaldisplay = not(normaldisplay)
        print "Display Mode:", "Normal" if normaldisplay else "Segmented" 

    img = cam.getDepth().flipHorizontal()
    img2 = cam.getImage().flipHorizontal()
    dist = img.colorDistance(SimpleCV.Color.BLACK).dilate(2)
    segmented = dist.stretch(200,255)
    binar = segmented.binarize(200)
    erode = binar.erode(2)
    blobs = erode.findBlobs()
    if blobs:
        circles = blobs.filter([b.isCircle(0.2) for b in blobs])
        if circles:
            img.drawCircle((circles[-1].x, circles[-1].y), circles[-1].radius(),SimpleCV.Color.BLUE,3)

    if normaldisplay:
        img.show()

    else:
        segmented.show()
```